# Dplyr: Apply condition on group by

Tags: r, dplyr, rstudio

I am trying to calculate the sum of jobs done by each id over a time frame(time_end and time_start ) and the maximum number of jobs done by any id over this time interval.

Each session of time_start and time_end is unique(timestamps). 
For example id1 has 2 sessions and id2 has 3 sessions:

```
id1 session 1:- 1am to 1:15 am - jobs done 100 

id1 session 2:- 1:18am to 1:30 am - jobs done 90

id2 session 3:- 1:02am to 1:14am - jobs done 110

id2 session 4:- 1:17am to 1:30am - jobs done 85

id2 session 5:- 1.31am to 1:40am - jobs done 75
```

Then i want the jobs done and max jobs done for each session:

```
session 1: jobs-100, max jobs-110

session 2: jobs-90, max jobs-90

session 3: 110, 110

session 4: 85, 90

session 5: 75,75


contri <- df1 %>% group_by (id, time_end , time_start) %>% summarise(jobs=n())

contri_max <- job_contribution %>% group_by(time_end , time_start) %>% summarise(jobs_max = max(jobs))
```

the 1st statement works fine , giving me the jobs per session, but i am not able to make the 2nd statement work.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the data we're dealing with (looks like `df1` and `job_contribution`)? Using `dput(dat)` may help communicate this.

Comment: hi zack, my database has following colums: jobid,session_id time_start, time_end. Thats all